# If the current buffer is named X, then do Y . . .; otherwise, do nothing

Tags: emacs

I'm looking (please) for an example of a function that will check to see if the active buffer is named X, and if so, then do Y . . .; otherwise, do nothing.

I do not want to switch to the buffer named X -- the function should only operate if I am already viewing an active buffer named X.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is the `buffer-name` function, it returns the name of a buffer (by default the current one) as a string.

```lisp
(if (equal (buffer-name) "X")
    ;; then...
  ;;else...
  )
```

For more information see the [introduction to Emacs Lisp](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/emacs-lisp-intro/html_node/Buffer-Names.html) or the [Emacs Lisp reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffer-Names.html#Buffer-Names).

Comment: Thank you very much -- greatly appreciated !!!  :)  I hadn't seen the `equal` used before, and I was trying things like (if (buffer-name "X") . . .

Comment: There has to be an operator in 'if'.  C-h f buffer-name returns just the name.

Comment: And, although it might be perfectly find for personal use, testing the name of a buffer is generally not the right thing to do.  Better test the major mode with `(derived-mode-p 'foo-mode)` or some other propery of the buffer.